# Can't store output from Colab into Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I wrote the code below but was unable to save it into Excel.

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

```
lists = ["FBRX", "GNLN", "TISI"]

for list in lists:
  url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{list}?p={list}"
  wd.get(url.format(list=list))
  EPS = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span').text
  AV = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/span').text
  OYT = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/span').text
  print(list,EPS,AV,OYT)
```

It will output the below table. But after that, I can't make the below into Excel. I had tried many methods but still fail. How can I fix this?

```
FBRX -1.6060 2,031,998 3.25
GNLN -1.0530 827,585 5.40
TISI -2.4640 545,536 10.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list of results in the for loop, use Pandas to make a data frame, and from this create the spreadsheet.

```
lists = ["FBRX", "GNLN", "TISI"]
result=[]  # empty list to start
for list in lists:
  url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{list}?p={list}" # use an f string to format
  wd.get(url.format(list=list))
  EPS = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span').text
  AV = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/span').text
  OYT = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/span').text
  print(list,EPS,AV,OYT)
  result.append([list,EPS,AV,OYT])   # add the row to the results

result

#[['FBRX', '-1.6060', '2,031,998', '3.25'],
# ['GNLN', '-1.0530', '827,585', '5.40'],
# ['TISI', '-2.4640', '545,536', '10.00']]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['List','EPS','AV','OYT'])
df.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

Note that I had to make the url generation use an f string to get the url correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, replace intead of the second part of the code you posted:

```
lists = ["FBRX", "GNLN", "TISI"]

import pandas as pd # Import Pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(len(lists)), index=lists) # Create empty DataFrame

for i, list in enumerate(lists):
  url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{list}?p={list}"
  wd.get(url.format(list=list))
  EPS = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span').text
  AV = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/span').text
  OYT = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/span').text
  print(list,EPS,AV,OYT)
  df[i][0]=EPS # Fill line i-th, column 0
  df[i][1]=AV # Fill line i-th, column 1
  df[i][2]=OYT # Fill line i-th, column 2

df.to_excel("output.xlsx") # Save to excel file
```

Basically, you create a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), which is like an empty table, by using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) ("a fast, powerful, flexible and easy to use open source data analysis and manipulation tool, built on top of the Python programming language"). Then, for every loop, you fill a line of the DataFrame.
Finally, you invoke the `to_excel()` method to store the file as `output.xlsx`. You will find it in the `content` folder of Google Colab.